# Django objects queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset, list-comprehension

I have a question regarding django queries. I have a query like so:

```
x = Foo.objects.order_by('date').values('amount')
```

and this returns something like:

```
[{'amount': Decimal('100.2200')},{'amount': Decimal('100.2200')}....]
```

What I want to do is get the standard deviation of these decimals but I cannot seem to figure out how to get them from the dictionary to just the decimals in a list. I tried a for statement but that doesn't work and list comprehension returns:

```
[Decimal('100.2200'), Decimal('100.2300')...]
```

With this code:

```
x = Foo.objects.order_by('date').values('amount')
x = ([amount.values()[0] for amount in x])
print x
```

Am I doing this wrong? Should I be making sql queries to the server if I want to get the info back and manipulate it?

Basically what I want to do is get the standard dev of all the amounts in a certain table based on specific filters...

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can get the list of decimals directly by [using `values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

```
qs = Foo.objects.order_by('date').values_list('amount', flat=True)
```

Secondly, if it is easier to calculate SD on floats, rather than on a list of decimals, you can do

```
qs = Foo.objects.order_by('date').values_list('amount', flat=True)
float_qs = map(float, qs)
```

Comment: You can also get SD directly from DB (SQLite requires an extension module for that, other DBs support it out of the box): `Foo.objects.all().aggregate(StdDev('amount'))` - [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#stddev)

Comment: @karthikr your first idea still prints out [Decimal('100.2200'), Decimal('100.2300')...]

Comment: @rafalmp does it matter if I'm using postgres? I'm running my program on C9 and cant update the python to run 3.

Comment: Thanks @karthikr second one is what I need I believe.

Comment: @HarpAngell Postgres supports StdDev since at least version 8.1 so I think there will be no problem.